# Find columns with values of certain format in Netezza

Tags: sql, regex, database, formatting, netezza

I'm trying to find certain info somewhere in a Netezza database. I searched all columns to see if they matched the name I was looking for with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _V_SYS_COLUMNS 
WHERE 
COLUMN_NAME like '%COW%' 
;
```

but no success. So I'd like to check the first value of each column in the database, and see if it's a string 7 characters long.

Any thoughts? I understand that it's a huge query that will like take a while to run.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the internet awhile back, I made this shell script to run in bash. It looks for a column value like a string. Depending on your flavor of SQL you can instead say `WHERE LEN(column_value) = 7`

It definitely takes a while to run, it actually created locks on our DB before it finished.

HTH

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# search.sh

DB=$1
STRING=$2

if [ "$DB" == "" -o "$STRING" == "" ]
then
  echo "usage:"
  echo "  alltextsearch DB STRING"
  exit 2
fi

sql $DB <<!EOT! | grep \| | grep -v '^|col1'

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.gen_sql (
     sql_command varchar(500)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
WITH NORECOVERY;
\g
INSERT INTO SESSION.gen_sql
SELECT 'SELECT ''OWNER.TABLE.COLUMN'',''VALUE''\g'
\g
INSERT INTO SESSION.gen_sql
SELECT SQUEEZE(
    'SELECT '''
        +table_owner+'.'+table_name+'.'+column_name+''','
        +column_name
    +' FROM '+table_owner+'.'+table_name
    +' WHERE '+column_name+' LIKE ''%$STRING%'' \g')
  FROM iicolumns
  WHERE column_datatype IN ('C','CHAR','TEXT','VARCHAR','NCHAR','NVARCHAR')
\g

COPY SESSION.gen_sql(sql_command= CHAR(0)nl )
   INTO 'temp.sql';
\g
\i temp.sql
!EOT!
```